# Python XML parser

Tags: python, xml

I have a complex XML I need to parse. I know how to parse some important tags.

XML data

```
<staff gid="2027930674">
    <task>Director</task>
    <person id="103045">Yōjirō Arai</person>
</staff>
```

XML full data

```
<ann>
<anime id="16989" gid="1524403706" type="movie" name="Taifū no Noruda" precision="movie" generated-on="2015-04-27T08:05:39Z">
<info gid="1917137337" type="Picture" src="http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/thumbnails/fit200x200/encyc/A16989-1917137337.1429892764.jpg" width="141" height="200">
<img src="http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/thumbnails/hotlink-fit200x200/encyc/A16989-1917137337.1429892764.jpg" width="141" height="200"/>
<img src="http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/thumbnails/hotlink-max500x600/encyc/A16989-1917137337.1429892764.jpg" width="353" height="500"/>
</info>
<info gid="1994323462" type="Main title" lang="JA">Taifū no Noruda</info>
<info gid="1715491679" type="Alternative title" lang="JA">台風のノルダ</info>
<info gid="898837990" type="Plot Summary">
On a certain isolated island, at a certain middle school, on the eve of the culture festival, Shūichi Azuma quits baseball after playing his whole life. He has a fight with his best friend Kenta Saijō. Then they suddenly meet a mysterious, red-eyed girl named Noruda, and a huge typhoon hits the middle school.
</info>
<info type="Vintage">2015-06-05</info>
<info gid="2492283870" type="Premiere date">2015-06-05 (Japan)</info>
<info gid="2453949568" type="Ending Theme">
"Arashi no Ato de" (嵐のあとで; After the Storm) by Galileo Galilei
</info>
<info gid="3199882585" type="Official website" lang="JA" href="http://typhoon-noruda.com/">「台風のノルダ」公式サイト</info>
<news datetime="2015-04-09T17:20:00Z" href="http://www.animenewsnetwork.com:/news/2015-04-09/studio-colorido-unveils-typhoon-noruda-anime-film/.86937">
Studio Colorido Unveils <cite>Typhoon Noruda</cite> Anime Film
</news>
<news datetime="2015-04-24T08:00:00Z" href="http://www.animenewsnetwork.com:/news/2015-04-24/studio-colorido-taifu-no-noruda-film-unveils-cast-more-staff-theme-song-band/.87470">
Studio Colorido's <i>Taifū no Noruda</i> Film Unveils Cast, More Staff, Theme Song Band
</news>
<staff gid="2027930674">
<task>Director</task>
<person id="103045">Yōjirō Arai</person>
</staff>
<staff gid="3870106504">
<task>Music</task>
<person id="110581">Masashi Hamauzu</person>
</staff>
<staff gid="2732633345">
<task>Character Design</task>
<person id="135767">Hiroyasu Ishida</person>
</staff>
<staff gid="1532205853">
<task>Art Director</task>
<person id="52564">Mika Nishimura</person>
</staff>
<staff gid="1006708772">
<task>Animation Director</task>
<person id="135767">Hiroyasu Ishida</person>
</staff>
<staff gid="934584477">
<task>Sound Director</task>
<person id="8849">Satoshi Motoyama</person>
</staff>
<staff gid="1138447906">
<task>Cgi Director</task>
<person id="42135">Norihiko Miyoshi</person>
</staff>
<staff gid="3178797981">
<task>Director of Photography</task>
<person id="24382">Mitsuhiro Sato</person>
</staff>
<cast gid="2645091588" lang="JA">
<role>Shūichi Azuma</role>
<person id="135769">Shūhei Nomura</person>
</cast>
<cast gid="2397297323" lang="JA">
<role>Kenta Saijō</role>
<person id="135770">Daichi Kaneko</person>
</cast>
<cast gid="2417172290" lang="JA">
<role>Noruda</role>
<person id="135771">Kaya Kiyohara</person>
</cast>
<credit gid="2574178211">
<task>Animation Production</task>
<company id="13518">Studio Colorido</company>
</credit>
</anime>
</ann>
```

Python code

```
#! /usr/bin/Python

# Import xml parser.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

# Import url library.
from urllib.request import urlopen

# Import sys library.
import sys

# XML to parse.
sampleUrl = "http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml?anime="

# Get the number of params we have in our application.
params = len (sys.argv)

# Check the number of params we have.
if (params == 1):
    print ("We need at least 1 anime identifier.")
else:
    for aid in range (1, params):
        # Read the xml as a file.
        content = urlopen (sampleUrl + sys.argv[aid])

        # XML content is stored here to start working on it.
        xmlData = content.readall().decode('utf-8')

        # Close the file.
        content.close()

        # Start parsing XML.
        root = ElementTree.fromstring (xmlData)

        # Extract classic data.
        for info in root.iter("anime"):
            print ("Id: " + info.get("id"))
            print ("Gid: " + info.get("gid"))
            print ("Name: " + info.get("name"))
            print ("Precision: " + info.get("precision"))
            print ("Type: " + info.get("type"))

        # Extract date and general poster.
        for info in root.iter ("info"):
            if ("Vintage" in info.get("type")):
                print ("Date: " + info.text)

            if ("Picture" in info.get("type")):
                print ("Poster: " + info.get("src"))

        # Extract aditional posters.
        for img in root.iter ("img"):
            print ("Poster: " + img.get("src"))

        print ("")

        # Extract all the staff of this anime.
        result = {}
        for staff in root.getiterator ("staff"):
            # Initialize values.
            task = ""
            value = {}

            for elem in staff.getchildren():
                if elem.tag == "task" :
                    task = elem.text
                elif elem.tag == "person" :
                    tmp = elem.text

                    if "id" in tmp:
                        value["id"] = tmp["id"]
                    value["name"] = elem.text
            if task :
                result[task] = value
        print (result)
```

I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse the entire XML. But I have problems to parse this section as one element. I need to store all data in another database as one field.

I need all this data together to realize this.

Sample: `{ "Director" : {"Name": "Yojiro Arai", "id" : "103045} }`

I don't know how to do this with the library `ElementTree`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show your progress, and also can you share the full xml?

Comment: I improved all the information about my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Parse input XML by `xml.etree.ElementTree` module.
2. Iterate every `staff` tag from the Parser Object by `getiterator`.
3. Iterate every child element of `staff` tag by `getchildren()`.
4. Create Dictionary.

**Demo**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as PARSER

data = """
<xml>
    <staff gid="2027930674">
        <task>Director</task>
        <person id="103045">ABC</person>
    </staff>
    <staff gid="2027930674">
        <task>Director1</task>
        <person id="1030452">XYZ</person>
    </staff>
</xml>    
    """

root = PARSER.fromstring(data)
result = {}
for i in root.getiterator("staff"):
    key = ""
    value = {}
    for j in i.getchildren():
        if j.tag=="task":
            key = j.text
        elif j.tag=="person":
            tmp = j.attrib
            if "id" in tmp:
                value["id"] = tmp["id"]
            value["name"] = j.text

    if key:
        result[key] = value

print result
```

**Output**:

```
{'Director': {'id': '103045', 'name': 'ABC'}, 'Director1': {'id': '1030452', 'name': 'XYZ'}}
```

Comment: Welcome. I will update answer with `lxml` module and `xpath` method.

Comment: @JasterTDC Clan:  ok, Can you update your answer or email me vivekbsable@gmail.com py file

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./AnimeXML.py", line 71, in <module>
    value["id"] = tmp["id"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Mail sent, check it when you can ^^.